MSPs for 2 of the PeerOrganizations are not being generated
I am trying to build and generate MSPs and certificate materials for my PeerOrganizations. I have 3 of them. The MSPs and the certificate materials for 2 of the organizations are not being generated. Only one of them are complete.  I am building a custom network, not the fabric-samples. Here is the folder structure:
peerOganization -> Org1 -> peers -> peer1 -> (msp (admincerts, cacerts, keystore, signcerts, tlscacerts), tls (priv_sk)
Now, for two of the organizations, the admincerts, cacerts etc., are not being generated. Only for one of them. I have tried everything possible to have them all generated, but to no avail. Here is a portions of my "generate.sh" script that generates the certificates:
function generateCerts() {
    cd /home/chukwueloka/github.com/Terarchy/backend/config/
    $FABRIC_BIN_PATH/cryptogen generate --config=/home/chukwueloka/github.com/Terarchy/backend/config/crypto-config.yaml --output=./crypto-config > full_cryptogen_output.log 2>&1
}

How do I fix this issue?
I have tried multiple tweaks to the "generate.sh" script. In the terminal, It shows the script worked, but just that the output is not complete like I showed above.

Not sure if this help. But every ID needs its own --mspdir.
If you can successfully enroll, could it be that the certs are generated all at the same location and one overwrite the other?
